# Acceder a un objeto y hacer un array para trabajar con el

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un **Objeto** del que quiero extraer un nuevo array de objetos para que unos campos en concreto esten al mismo nivel.

La llamada me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
0: Object {
  id: 328,
  userId: "xxx",
  accountingDate: "2022-07-29T00:00:00.000+00:00",
  …
}
accountingDate: "2022-07-29T00:00:00.000+00:00"
category: Object {
  id: 7,
  subCategories: null,
  name: "Electricidad"
}
ch4: 0
co2: 0
date: null
description: null
h2o: 584795
id: 328
n2o: 0
subCategory: Object {
  id: 12,
  name: "Factura agua",
  alcance: 1
}
alcance: 1
id: 12
name: "Factura agua"
```

Para trabajar con el necesito el **category.name** y el **subcategory.name**.

He hecho un map:

```
const emisionsMap = emisions.map((v)=>{
    return v
})
```

pero me devuelve lo mismo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para acceder al *category.name* y *subcategory.name*?

Si pongo *category.name*, me da `undefined`.

Comment: Eso no parece un Objeto, parece un Array con un Objeto como primer elemento. Tendrías que acceder mediante el nombre del Array, posición 0. Por ejemplo: `arr[0].category.name`. Saludos

Comment: si, cierto, es un array de objetos, pero quiero acceder a el siempre, para pintarlo, sin poner la posicion

Comment: `map` te devuelve otro array, por lo cual no estás haciendo nada. Podrías usar la siguiente sintaxis: `const [ miObjeto ] = miArray;`. Suponiendo que el Array contiene al menos un objeto, luego podrías acceder con `miObjeto.category.name`. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo depende de lo que quieras que incluya el nuevo array. Si solo esos 2 campos o todos los que tiene y a mayores los 2 que dices en el primer nivel.

```
const emisionsMap = emisions.map((v)=>{
    return {categoryName: v.category.name, subCategoryName: v.subCategory.name} // esto te devuelve un objeto solo con estas 2 propiedades
    return {...v, categoryName: v.category.name, subCategoryName: v.subCategory.name} // esto te devuelve el objeto inicial + las 2 propiedades nuevas
})
```